# How set labels below figure

Tags: gnuplot

Please i have this figure: [image]

i ask how can set labels tamisag.data:using 1:2 below figure ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set key outside
set key bottom right
```

For help on a command in gnuplot use

```
help <cmd>
```

e.g.

```
help set key
```

Complete info:

```
set key {on|off} {default}
                {left | right | top | bottom | outside | below | <position>}
                {Left | Right} {{no}reverse}
                {samplen <sample_length>} {spacing <vertical_spacing>}
                {width <width_increment>}
                {height <height_increment>}
                {{no}autotitles}
                {title "<text>"} {{no}enhanced}
                {{no}box { {linestyle | ls <line_style>}
                           | {linetype | lt <line_type>}
                             {linewidth | lw <line_width>}}}
        unset key
        show key
```

Docs:
http://lavica.fesb.hr/cgi-bin/info2html?%28gnuplot%29key

Demo:
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/key.html

Comment: thank you so much for answer:) i ask if it's possible under the title of figure "tamis" ?

Comment: It looks like there is not space to do that, as that is what it tries to do. Doc: "Putting keys
 outside to the right, they occupy as few columns as possible, and
 putting them below, as many columns as possible (depending of the
 length of the labels), thus stealing as little space from the graph as possible." Try making the titles short (plot 'file' with lines title 'newtitle').